# How to click on the span type element in selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
<span class="tm-button-icon__label taLabel _flex">
   <span class="tm-button-icon__text">
         Demo
   </span>
   <span class="tm-button-icon__inner-description taOption">
         Demo001
   </span>
</span>
```

Please help on how to click span based element?

Comment: Please, could you elaborate? E.g., show the error message and the code you are currently running; double check if the element is visible or inside an iframe.

Comment: You can click `span` elements just like you click on any other element. Define a proper locator and use `click()` method against that.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below xpath

```
//span[contains(text(),'Demo')]

//span[contains(text(),'Demo001')]
```

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `xpath`,it may work

```
//span[@class="tm-button-icon__label taLabel _flex"][@class='tm-button-icon__inner-description taOption']
```

Comment: Hi Ash, your post has been flagged as there's not much of an answer. Are you able to explain why might this work? Where did OP go wrong? What might OP do in future to avoid this?